# ActiveRecord Insert data from XLS (script already developed, need help to make it run inside the rails env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to push some data from and old application using access to the new one that I created with Rails. I've exported Access data to .xls accessing it with the gem `roo`.

It works pretty fine, I created a script and by printing results I'm sure it does all properly, now I'd like to have it to insert automatically this data inside the database, accessing the rails application models.

I tried putting the file under my rails' `lib/` directory and then I required it within the `environments/development.rb`, but when I import the ruby file it claims that cannot find some variables I need to do the processing.

For completeness this is the whole source code I developed to extract data from the xls and edit it to match the new db schema.

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

user_id_conversion = {119 => 10, 152 => 11, 145 => 12, 161 => 13, 163 => 14, 158 => 15}
conversion_hours = {15 => 14, 17 => 16, 19 => 18}
hostess_id_conversion = {139 => 9, 157 => 17, 153 => 18, 110 => 20, 40 => 19, 141 => 21, 121 => 22, 151 => 23}
status_conversion = {1 => "Inserito", 2 => "Rifiutato", 3 => "Visitato", 4 => "Inserito", 5 => "Ricontattare", 6 => "Vendita"}
mall_id_conversion = {51 => 1, 56 => 2, 53 => 3, 54 => 4, 59 => 5, 65 => 6}

xls = Excel.new("/home/lex/Scrivania/appointments.xls")
xls.default_sheet = xls.sheets.first

city_list = []

# change this to current row numbers
1.upto(3829) do |line|
  uid        = xls.cell(line,'B').to_i

  if user_id_conversion.has_key? uid
    id         = xls.cell(line, 'A')
    uid        = user_id_conversion[uid]
    name       = xls.cell(line, 'F')
    surname    = xls.cell(line, 'E')
    city       = xls.cell(line, 'O')
    street     = xls.cell(line, 'G')
    start_at   = xls.cell(line, 'C')
    start_time = xls.cell(line, 'D')/60/60
    street_no  = xls.cell(line, 'M')
    telephone  = xls.cell(line, 'H')
    mobile     = xls.cell(line, 'I')
    email      = xls.cell(line, 'J')
    notes      = xls.cell(line, 'L')
    agent_note = xls.cell(line, 'U')
    status     = xls.cell(line, 'S')
    signed_by  = xls.cell(line, 'P')
    mall       = xls.cell(line, 'T')

    # we only want to move May -> future
    if start_at.month >= Date.today.month
      ##
      # COMPATIBILITY MODE
      ##
      if conversion_hours.has_key? start_time
        compatibility = true
      else
        compatibility = false
      end

      ##
      # WHO SIGNED THAT APPOINTMENT?
      ##
      if hostess_id_conversion.has_key? signed_by
        signed_by = hostess_id_conversion[signed_by]
      elsif user_id_conversion.has_key? signed_by
        signed_by = user_id_conversion[signed_by]
      else
        signed_by = -1 # display "user deleted"
      end

      ##
      # APPOINTMENT OR EXCLUDED FIELD?
      ##
      available = true
      if status == 4
        available = false
      end
      status = status_conversion[status]

      ##
      # todo SELECT CITY ID FROM DATABASE
      ##
      # city = Municipality.find_by_name(city)
      #

      ##
      # CONVERT MALL_ID
      ##
      if mall_id_conversion.has_key? mall
        mall = mall_id_conversion[mall]
      else
        mall = nil
      end

      ##
      # EMAIL is REQUIRED
      ##
      no_email = false
      if email.blank?
        no_email = true
      end

      ##
      # CONVERT APPOINTMENT DATES TO NEW ONES
      ##
      if compatibility
        old_start_at = DateTime.new start_at.year, start_at.month, start_at.day, start_time
        start_at     = DateTime.new start_at.year, start_at.month, start_at.day, conversion_hours[start_time]
      else
        old_start_at = nil
        start_at     = DateTime.new start_at.year, start_at.month, start_at.day, start_time
      end

      ##
      # todo interesting products
      #    serramenti: boolean, tende_sole: boolean, tecnic: boolean,
      #    tende_veranda: boolean, porte_interne: boolean, tapparelle: boolean, blindati: boolean,
      #    zanzariere: boolean,
      ##

      ##
      # todo INSERT THIS APPOINTMENT
      ##
=begin
      if available == false
        Event.new(
          :event_calendar_id => User.find(uid).event_calendar,
          :status => "Inserito",
          :available => false
          )
      else
        Event.new(
          :event_calendar_id => User.find(uid).event_calendar,
          :signed_by_id => User.find_by_id(signed_by),
          :mall_id => Mall.find_by_id(mall),
          :status => status,
          :name => name,
          :surname => surname,
          :street => street,
          :street_no => street_no,
          :city_id => city.name,
          :telephone => telephone,
          :mobile => mobile,
          :email => email,
          :no_email => no_email,
          :inserting_notes => notes,
          :seller_notes => agent_note,
          :start_at => start_at,
          :available => true,
          group_id: 3,
          :compatibility_start_at => old_start_at
          )
      end
=end

    end
  end
end
```

How can I make this work inside the rails environment?
I was thinking to make something like a class or a function to be run inside the `rails c` console because I'll need to run this this evening to get the most updated database version, extract the xls with updated records and do the magic.

Sorry if this may seem a noob question but I'm new to Ruby.

P.S. I'm using Rails 3.2.3 w/Ruby 1.9.3
P.P.S. I inserted 'roo' inside the Gemfile since it was first not finding the gem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
rails runner path/to/script
```

Then rails will load the rails environment and then run your script